# worker directives in apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2

we are running apache 2.2.26 as a proxy server and following are its setting for worker module.

```
ServerLimit 3000


<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients        6000
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Can someone please help me out with relevant definitions of above directives with an example. I have checked multiple sites and I am confused what above directives stand for, multiple sites and multiple meanings. Here is what I understood,

```
StartServers - Number of apache child worker process that shall start when apache starts.
ThreadsPerChild - Number of threads created by individual child processes.
```

In my existing setup when I run `ps -efL | grep <child PID>`, I get count of threads(29) exceeding the value of ThreadsPerChild (25). Is this expected ?

Please can someone help me with these definitions in the lamest way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that the "children" are lightweight processes using the same PID?   What exactly is your OS?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 and we have apache installed under chroot.

Comment: You should check the output of the grep, not just the count, which contains at least the parent and the grep itself as extra!   In the default apache configuration, the meaning of those directives is explained.  BTW, RHEL 6 ends maintenance support in november.

Comment: this is the grep command that I run. ps -efL | grep PID | grep -v grep | grep -c httpd.worker and the number that I get is greater than the ThreadsPerChild.

Comment: 2 servers x 25 ThreadsPerChild = 50 ?

Comment: yep. That should be expected value, however when I grep I get 29*2 threads spawning out of two child process.

Comment: since my serverlimit is set to 3000 and threadsperchild to 25, my apache is capable of creating 75000 client connection but since my maxclient is set to 6000, the number of concurrent client connection will be max limited to 6000 and not 75000.

am I speaking right ?

Comment: 75000 probably exceeds the nofiles limit. Even 6000 active connections may be more than your system can chew. Perhaps you can put a cache in front, like Varnish?

Comment: we have no of open files set to 65535 and user processes also set to 65535. So 6000 concurrent client connections does not seem huge enough considering that we have one single instance of apache running.